# Get distinct code client with different language

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains code client, client name, language.

[image]

How could I get distinct client code and name

```
select distinct code, name
```

But it sometimes returns name with duplicate name. when name it is not correctly written.

Comment: Please show what you want to return, and what you're getting now.

Comment: Do not post your data as image, use text format instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have different values in the name for the same client code:

```
Stéphanie
St&phanie
```

We can tackle this by selecting only one of them using a min or max, depending on which result you want:

```
select client_code, max(client_name)
from MyTable
group by client_code
```